# How to create a list file of some files?

Tags: linux, shell-script

i have a bunch of files from log1 to log164, 
how can i create a file like below ordering...
please help me...

1. log1.gz
2. log10.gz
3. log100.gz
4. log101.gz
5. log102.gz
6. log103.gz
7. log104.gz
8. log105.gz
9. log106.gz
   ...etc

Comment: i need like these...
log1.gz
log10.gz
log100.gz
log101.gz
log102.gz
log103.gz
log104.gz
log105.gz
log106.gz
...etc

Comment: What do you need? A enumerated ordered list (a list with row number, a file name per row and rows are separated by new line) or an ordered list where each file name is separated by space!

Comment: separeated new line

Comment: What's wrong with `ls > listfile`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an ordered list by simply using `ls -v`. But the next formatting part is a bit trickier. If you need an enumerated list (I am assuming the formating is same as in your question) you can use awk. Use pipe to feed the `ls -v` output to awk.

> ls -v | awk '{print NR ".",$0}'

If you don't need the enumeration, then it can be done without awk. In the output of `ls -v` replace the spaces by a new line character.

> ls -v | tr ' ' '\n'